# Something about python class

Tags: python

I could not figure out how two classes interact each other with python. This is my code.

```
class Interval(object):
     def __init__(self, s=0, e=0):
         self.start = s
         self.end = e

class Solution(object):
    def canAttendMeetings(self, intervals):
        """
        :type intervals: List[Interval]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        intervals.sort()

        for i in range(1, len(intervals)):
            if intervals[i].start < intervals[i-1].end:
                return False

        return True       

B= Solution()
print B.canAttendMeetings([[20,30],[25,30]])
```

The result is 'list' object has no attribute 'start'
So could you tell me how to use both these classes.

Comment: How are you expecting `[20,30]` to turn into an Interval?

Comment: sorry for that I mean I can't use the first class Interval's attribute start or end. Could you help me?

Comment: Just because the variable is called `intervals` doesn't mean it contains an `Interval`. You're passing `[[20,30], [25,30]]` as `intervals` to `canAttendMeetings`. That's a list of lists. Nothing in this code makes an `Interval`.

Comment: You can't figure it out, simply because they don't interact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does this:

```
B.canAttendMeetings([[20,30],[25,30]])
```

which passes

```
[[25,30],[25,30]]
```

in the "intervals" parameter:

```
def canAttendMeetings(self, intervals):
```

You and I know they are supposed to be `Interval`s but you haven't told Python that, so as far as it knows, they are lists. The first one is a list containing [25, 30].

Try the following:

```
class Interval(object):
     def __init__(self, s=0, e=0):
         self.start = s
         self.end = e

class Solution(object):
    def canAttendMeetings(self, intervals):
        """
        :type intervals: List[Interval]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        print type(intervals)

        return True       

B = Solution()
print B.canAttendMeetings([Interval(20,30),Interval(25,30)])
```

See: http://ideone.com/V38Erj

It prints: `<type 'list'>`

Again: intervals is just a list at this point, just because it's called `intervals` doesn't mean that's what it contains.

In order for the list elements to become `Interval`s you'll have to create some `Interval`s.

```
B.canAttendMeetings([Interval(20,30), Interval(25,30)])
```

Full code:

```
class Interval(object):
     def __init__(self, s=0, e=0):
         self.start = s
         self.end = e

class Solution(object):
    def canAttendMeetings(self, intervals):
        """
        :type intervals: List[Interval]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        intervals.sort()

        for i in range(1, len(intervals)):
            if intervals[i].start < intervals[i-1].end:
                return False

        return True       

B = Solution()
print B.canAttendMeetings([Interval(20,30),Interval(25,30)])
```

http://ideone.com/OXZ8Lj

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. I mixed these up, thank you again for your help.

Comment: No problem - if this solved your problem, remember to click the check mark next to the answer.